# Find the percentage of null values across multiple databases

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm lost and my level in sql is pretty average but I need to find the percentage of null values in each column of each table across multiple databases.

I've found this cursor somwhere and it gives me the right percentage but only for a specific database. How can I implement this for all my databases in a single table?

```
DECLARE @DatabaseName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @SchemaName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @TableName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @ColumnName VARCHAR(100)
DECLARE @FullyQualifiedTableName VARCHAR(500)

--Create Temp Table to Save Results
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Results') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE #Results

CREATE TABLE #Results (
DatabaseName VARCHAR(100)
,SchemaName VARCHAR(100)
,TableName VARCHAR(100)
,ColumnName VARCHAR(100)
,TotalTableRowCount INT
,NullRecordCount INT
)

DECLARE Cur CURSOR
FOR
SELECT C.Table_CataLog, C.Table_Schema, C.Table_Name, C.Column_Name
,'[' + C.Table_CataLog + ']' + '.[' + C.Table_Schema + '].' + '[' + C.Table_Name + ']' AS FullQualifiedTableName
FROM information_schema.COLUMNS C
INNER JOIN information_Schema.Tables T ON C.Table_Name = T.Table_Name
AND T.Table_Type = 'BASE TABLE'
and C.IS_Nullable='YES'


OPEN Cur


FETCH NEXT
FROM Cur
INTO @DatabaseName
,@SchemaName
,@TableName
,@ColumnName
,@FullyQualifiedTableName

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = NULL

SET @SQL = ' Select ''' + @DatabaseName + ''' AS DatabaseName, '''
+ @SchemaName + ''' AS TableName,
''' + @TableName + ''' AS SchemaName,
''' + @ColumnName + ''' AS ColumnName,
(Select count(*) from ' + @FullyQualifiedTableName + ' with (nolock))
AS TotalTableRowCount,
count(*) as NullRecordCount from ' + @FullyQualifiedTableName
+ 'with (nolock) Where ' + @ColumnName + ' IS NULL'

--Print @SQL
INSERT INTO #Results
EXEC (@SQL) 

FETCH NEXT
FROM Cur
INTO @DatabaseName
,@SchemaName
,@TableName
,@ColumnName
,@FullyQualifiedTableName
END

CLOSE Cur

DEALLOCATE Cur
```

Comment: I would honestly ask "Why do you need to do this?" I find that often these "needs" are for completely arbitrary requirements and normally as a result of an [XY problem](//xyproblem.info).

Comment: Here is an SP that is supposed to allow you to do what you want: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2201/making-a-more-reliable-and-flexible-spmsforeachdb/